# Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, beautiful-soup

Имеется код, который берет адреса. При выполнении выдает ошибку

> Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json


JSON = 'location.json'
r = requests.get('https://omsk.yapdomik.ru/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
locations = soup.find('div', {'class': ['site-footer__address-list']})

with open('location.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(locations, file)
```

Comment: Нужно что-бы locations был словарем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно, что-бы `locations` был типа dict. Вы же забираете часть разметки HTML, из которой нужно достать данные, прежде чем записывать в json. Если вы хотите достать локации, то сделать это можно таким образом:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json


JSON = 'location.json'
r = requests.get('https://omsk.yapdomik.ru/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
locations = soup.find('div', {'class': ['site-footer__address-list']}).find_all("li")

locations_dict = {"locations": []}
for loc in locations:
    locations_dict["locations"].append(loc.text)

with open('location.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
    json.dump(locations_dict, file, indent=4)
```

Comment: параметр indent - это отступы, без него у вас все данные будут в одну строку, в который сложно будет что-то разобрать

Comment: вроде более-менее понял. только теперь json записывает в юникоде u0433 и подобное

Comment: укажи в json.dump() ещё один параметр - ensure_ascii=False, посмотри в подсказках, возможно несколько букв отличаются

Comment: спасибо большое
но сейчас понял, что все делал не так, как надо. поэтому придется начинать все заново и по другому)